# An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem

Tags: apex, visualforce, liveagent

> An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. Error ID: 442694351-290 (1474324866)

What is  this error? please let me know If anybody knows about this error .

Comment: welcome to the community, Please go through the how to ask a good question section http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask prior to ask a question. From your question it is not clear what you want to do so please modify your question and add what are the steps you are following which giving this error.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into a gack. R&D should already be working on it or have it in their queue. Note that Salesforce specifically calls out that the error is **not your fault** in describing what a gack is.

> ## [What Is A Gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html)
>
> If you’ve been around Salesforce long enough, you have probably encountered a screen that looks like this one here:
>
> [image: gack]
>
> What you are looking at is what we call a GACK. A gack is our blue screen of death, our frowny Mac icon, our “the number you have reached is no longer in service”, our “Jedediah has died of dysentery”. A gack is what happens when an error got thrown within our application and we didn’t catch it and handle it.
>
> What this means is that it’s not your fault. It’s ours. That’s why we apologize in that message. Sorry!
>
> This friendly message is the above-water portion of a huge iceberg of functionality. The numbers you see are part of an elaborate system for efficiently bringing these events to the attention of R&D. This post will help you understand that system, and how you can help us in getting you running safely. (Hint: steer away from icebergs.)

Answer (score 0):

You should open a support ticket with SalesForce, as instructed. They will be able to trace the Error ID and tell you what is causing the problem. From experience, the error codes are unique to your individual error.

Comment: I wish it were that easy. I just tried this the other day and tier one would not escalate and just closed the case. Said they did not have access to any logs. I would not waste your time unless it is business critical and you can find no workaround